# Django Boolean is "True" after migration and not selected in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

I am trying to add a row to my Model and have that option editable in a ModelForm in Django. I want the field to be True by default.  Here's what I'm adding to my model:

```
field_name = models.BooleanField(default=1)
```

Then, I use South to do a migration. Everything works perfectly, except instead of my database full of "1" for this field, it's full of "True" and for some reason, when it pulls up the ModelForm, the checkbox isn't checked when "True". When I change "True" to "1" in the database, it is checked.

Trying to find a good solution here. Seems odd.

Comment: Boolean values in Python are either `True` or `False`. If it's 0 or 1, or whatever, it's not Boolean. Even if it's a `TINYINT` in your database, Django converts it to `True` or `False` before your code gets it. P.S. While the box isn't checked in your ModelForm, see if it is in the admin.

Comment: It is not checked in Google Admin. However, when I change the value to 1, it shows checked.

Comment: sqlite is not a production db. You may ignore the bugs it makes. Test your application on a real db, like postgresql, and don't trust what sqlite may produce in development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this.

```
field_name = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

What database are you using, does your database support Boolean fields? Or does it use a smallint field with 0 and 1 for false and true?

Comment: See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#booleanfield-on-mysql

Comment: I'm using sqlite locally, which is where I'm seeing this issue.

Comment: what is the column type in sqlite?